# Enum to string C# and JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript

In my .aspx I've got the following javascript variable defined:

```
var action = <%=ProdView %>
```

In code-behind this returns a custom enum value:

```
protected ProductView ProdView { get; private set; }
```

I would figure that this would automatically be converted to a string in javascript?  Looks like no because I get the runtime error "Item is not defined" where Item is the value ProdView.Item.  Ultimately I want the action's value to be "Item" as the value.

Here's the Enum:

```
  public enum ProductView
  {
   Product,
   Item
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var action = '<%=ProdView.ToString() %>'
```

Don't forget the quotes.

***Edit to respond on coffee addicts comment***

You have to remember that the code is executed twice, first at server side to generate the text string:

```
var action = '<%=ProdView.ToString() %>'
```

is executed by ASP.net and turned into a complete string  before returning it to the web browser

```
var action = 'lalalalala'
```

And the actual java script is executed in the web browser.

So ASP.net have nothing to do with the actual javascript execution. It's job is only to generate HTML/javascript/css that will be sent back to the webbrowser.

Comment: Yep - what he said. Even mine didn't have the quotes - and mine would break too.

Comment: I guess I don't understand under the hood how JS interprets this line of code in terms of shoving server-side references into a string.